# Countdowntimer sometimes bugs after phone lock

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have strange problem with countdowntimer. Normally it works well, but sometimes (like 5% chance or so) after locking phone and unlocking it bugs like on video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nbp63gmv4spzgf/bug.mp4

Here i set the timer:

```
private void startCurrentLessonTimer() {    
        if(lessonsBreak) {
            lessonsBreakEnd.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) / 3600, ((currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60, 
                    (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 60));
        } else {
            currentLessonEnd.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) / 3600, ((currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60, 
                    (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 60));
        }

        currentLessonTimer = new CountDownTimer(currentLessonTimeInMillis, 1000) {
            long hours = (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) / 3600;
            long minutes = ((currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 3600) / 60;
            long seconds = (currentLessonTimeInMillis / 1000) % 60;

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if(seconds == 0) {        
                    seconds = 59;
                    if(minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
                        minutes = 59;
                        hours--;
                    }
                    else {
                        minutes--;
                    }
                } else {
                    seconds--;
                }
                if(lessonsBreak) {
                    lessonsBreakEnd.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
                } else {
                    currentLessonEnd.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                getNextLesson();
                getCurrentLesson();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

And this function (inside getData()) is called in onResume()

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getData();
    }
```

onPause():

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        clean();
    }
```

clean():

```
private void clean() {
        if(currentLessonTimer != null) {
            currentLessonTimer.cancel();
            currentLessonTimer = null;
        }
    }
```

I tried to use other countdowntimer, but this problem still occurs (but not that often).

Code: http://pastebin.com/nKsasJ1S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you get multiple `CountDownTimer`s refreshing your UI. This leads me to your `clean()` function like it's not doing it's job on every `onPause()`. So on next `onResume()` there will be multiple `CountDownTimer`s.

I don't know how `CountDownTimer` works but the thing I can think of is that your `CountDownTimer` is `start()`ed but still not initialized (`currentLessonTimer` is still `null`) when `onPause()` is occurring not letting `clean()` to run so it'd be a race condition that could be avoided with a `Service` for example.